# css being applied to all elements in array

Tags: jquery, foreach, each

When I run this function the CSS is being applied to all the buttons. How do I modify so that the CSS only gets modified for the buttons where the buttonAttr attribute equals disabled?

```
$('.product_tile .addtocartbutton').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var buttonAttr = $this.attr('disabled');

    if($this.attr('disabled') = 'disabled'){
        $this.css('background','#ccc');     
    } else {
        $this.css('background','#EEDED1');
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this small modification;

```
$('.product_tile .addtocartbutton').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if($this.is(":disabled")){
        $this.css('background','#ccc');     
    } else {
        $this.css('background','#EEDED1');
    }   
});
```

This takes advantage of the jquery `:disabled` selector, [link](https://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) to documentation.

---

Edit:
Another option is a solely CSS solution, taking advantage of the `attribute selector`

```css
input[type='button'] {
  background: #eeded1;
}

input[type='button'][disabled] {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' value='Disabled' disabled='disabled' /><br /><br />
<input type='button' value='Active' />
```

Comment: @Taplar, I edited to include a pure css solution.  I would think this would be the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't check boolean attributes using the `attr` function. Use `prop` instead to return the actual value.

```
$('.product_tile .addtocartbutton').each(function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled') ? $(this).css('background','#ccc') : $(this).css('background','#EEDED1');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need double or triple equal signs to do a comparison.

```
 if($this.buttonAttr == 'disabled')
```

Comment: Thanks, i noticed I also have to change my if condition.

Answer (score 1):

No need of writing long code just use this

```
 $(':button[disabled="disabled"]').css('background','#ccc');
```

or

```
$('.product_tile .addtocartbutton :button[disabled="disabled"]')).css('background','#ccc');
```

depending on your scenario. 
Using :button applies to both button and input type="button"